# Количество товара на странице, как это реализуется? Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

верстаю макет для обучения и столкнулся с такой задачей. На странице изначально отображается 16 карточек товара, но можно через фильтр делать 12 и 24. Как это реализуется? Через Ajax? В сети много ответов для CMS, но мне нужно в чистом виде.

Comment: Хоть ajax, хоть и через перезагрузку страницы с передачей get параметра.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший вариант для понимания.

На реальном проекте реализация будет отличаться.

```
<?php

$limit = isset($_GET['limit']) ? $_GET['limit'] : 16;

// Теперь $limit содержит необходимое количество карточек для вывода

?>

<!-- Фильтры для выбора количества -->

<a href="?limit=12">12</a>
<a href="?limit=16">16</a>
<a href="?limit=24">24</a>


<h5>Выводим <?= $limit ?> карточек</h5>
```